# Trouble upgrading ubuntu 17.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS “Bionic Beaver

Tags: upgrade

I took as many screen shots to help explain what is going on. I have 17.04 and want to upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS “Bionic Beaver.

[Software Updater / Partial Upgrade Doesn't Help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9i3i.png)

[Package Manager Not Opening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmEIR.png)

[Was opening package manager not anymore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TDdD.png)

[this line was opening package manager but not anymore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiEgP.png)

[Software and Updates No Help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztsd0.png)

[About Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMmpb.png)